# How to expose a mongo server in kubernetes using Ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I want to expose a mongo server which is running in the cluster using Ingress, I have read online that Ingress is not exactly the best method for this since it is used for resolving Application Layer traffic and works on HTTP/HTTPS but I wanted to know if there is a work around with my not using LoadBalancer or Nodeport. I'm using nginx-ingress.

I have tried exposing it via Ingress but it isn't working. Though I haven't tried traefik but I don't think it will work.

Comment: Setting up a LoadBalancer service is really going to be the easiest option if you want to expose a non-HTTP service outside of the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/

Nginx-ingress supports this.

Minikube has a tutorial on how to do this (if you're using Minikube)
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/nginx_tcp_udp_ingress/

Fun fact: The Gitlab helm chart uses this to expose port 22 so that users can clone git repos over ssh.

https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/advanced/external-nginx/#helm-deployment